# php is altering original filename

Tags: php, escaping

I have a file upload, and try to take care of strange filenames by removing unwanted characters.
But I have the situation where I just played around with unwanted (chars in) filenames and got the following result:

My Bad Filename is: `1\;ping\ -c1\ 1.1.1.1`
Firefox is sending:
`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="send_file"; filename="1\;ping\ -c1\ 1.1.1.1"`

But PHP's `$_FILES['send_file']['name']` object is just giving me `1.1.1.1` (with a leading space) as name.

In general that would be ignorable but I'd like to understand what is happening here

What is happening here? Please enlighten me

**Software used:**

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Apache 2.4.29
- PHP-FPM 7.2
- Firefox 70

Comment: Could you please share with us more detail about your server ? Apache or nginx, or php console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's `$_FILES['send_file']['name']` does **not** equal `Content-Disposition`'s `filename="..."` value.

PHP is doing some sanitizing: removes *path* and stores only *name of the file*, like it said in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> *$_FILES['userfile']['name']*
>
> The original name of the file on the client machine.

*Removing path* means that everything before last slash/backslash (including them) is removed, that's what you got.

Answer (score 1):

It relate to very old issue since 2005, and basically the character  `\` is not valid character for the file name in Window

You can found more detail here, and old bug with status *Won't fix*

https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=5681

Comment: ok, so PHP is doing this on purpose? Because the behavior in the link you posted is different from the outcome I experience. They just seem to encounter a removal of those chars, rather than my outcome which cuts the string and only returns everything after the last backslash. Also do you have any information provided by PHP on this case? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about \\ instead of \ ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, as you have figured out, never use `$_FILES['send_file']['name']` without any validation.

It's impossible to tell what your `$_FILES['send_file']['name']` will be, because this is set by the browser. So your browser pre-processes the filename and removes any unwanted characters.

---

Let's take a look at what happens when you select a file and submit your form (headers abbreviated):

```
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 1234
Origin: http://localhost:8080
[...]
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="send_file"; filename="hello.pdf"
Content-Type: application/x-object

... contents of file goes here ...
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

In this case, `$_FILES['send_file']['name']` would be set to `hello.pdf`.

---

In short, neither PHP nor your webserver do (to my knowledge) any preprocessing of the file name. It's purely set by the operating system and the browser of your user.

Comment: So you are saying that the Browser is responsible for my experienced escaping even though Firefox reports `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="send_file"; filename="1\;ping\ -c1\ 1.1.1.1"`this? I'll validate thiss in the next 12h, and let you know. Thank you for now!

Comment: That's interesting. Is this `Content-Disposition` header what your server sees? Is `1\;ping\ -c1\ 1.1.1.1` an actual filename or are the escape slashes added by the browser?

Comment: Copied it right from the Browser. Chrome acted the same (Had no Safari around, and no IE). So the browser seems to be out of the race.  If I'll have time, I could check the header with a TCP dump to see if the browser output is somewhat missleading. The slashes are part of the Filename, and NOT escape sequences by the browser!